# Dynamic memory allocation with realloc

Tags: c

Suppose we have this code:

```
 int *h;

 for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
     h = malloc(sizeof(int));
     h[i] = i;
 }
```

The issue I have here is that **I want to start with an empty array**, i.e. just declaring`int *h`, and then `*h` will grow at the runtime using `realloc`. I tried using this example but it does not allocate a sequential memory places and also does not work. I understand that `realloc` works after allocating by malloc so is there any workaround of that?

Comment: This `h = malloc(sizeof(int));` allocates only an `int`

Comment: your only allocating space for `h[0]` and leaking the previous `h`

Comment: A pointer is no array!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accommodate exactly what you are trying to do, `realloc(NULL, size)` does the same thing as `malloc(size)`.  You can write your loop like this:

```
int *h = 0;
size_t avail = 0;

for (size_t i = 0; more_data_available(); i++) {
    if ((i+1) * sizeof(int) > avail) {
        avail = avail == 0 ? 8*sizeof(int) : avail*2;
        int *nh = realloc(h, avail);
        if (!nh) abort();
        h = nh;
   }
   h[i] = next_data_item();
}
```

But note the convoluted `?:` expression I had to use to enlarge `avail`.  That would be cleaner if I start the loop with some space already allocated; and then I can just use `malloc` normally:

```
size_t avail = 8 * sizeof(int);
int *h = malloc(avail);
if (!h) abort();

for (size_t i = 0; more_data_available(); i++) {
    if ((i+1) * sizeof(int) > avail) {
        avail *= 2;
        int *nh = realloc(h, avail);
        if (!nh) abort();
        h = nh;
    }
    h[i] = next_data_item();
}
```

Comment: Can I ask another question: How do I determine the size of h? I mean when **I want to search for an element in h**, I need the size for h to iterate over it, right?

Comment: There is no library support for that in C.  Your code will need to remember the largest value of `i` for which `h[i]` is meaningful data.  (This is *not* the same as `avail` in my sample code.)

Comment: Thanks alot ... appreciate it